# Apply UFormat to System.DateTime variable

Tags: powershell, datetime

I am trying to apply a specific format to a DateTime variable on Powershell, but I am finding it impossible.

This works fine:

```
>> Get-Time -UFormat "%Y%m%d-%h%M%S"
20210412-135938
```

But if I try to assign it to a variable and then do the formatting, I encounter an error, for example

```
 $startDate=Get-Date -Year 2021 -Month 01 -Day 01 -Hour 11 -Minute 00 -Second 00
 $startDate=$startDate.addHours(10)
 $startDate=$startDate.addHours(23)
 ($startDate) -UFormat "%Y%m%d-%h%M%S"
```

Then I get an `Token Uformat unexpected` error.
Could someone throw some light as on how to get this formatting to work?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more ways of formatting a date that are more 'PowerShelly' then using UFormat:

1. use the .Net `ToString()` method:

```
(Get-Date).AddHours(10).ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss")
```

2. use the -Format parameter of `Get-Date`:

```
$startDate = (Get-Date).AddHours(10)
Get-Date -Date $startDate -Format "yyyyMMdd-HHmmss"
```

3. or use the `-f` format operator:

```
'{0:yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}' -f (Get-Date).AddHours(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an existing `[datetime]` value to `Get-Date`'s `-Date` parameter:

```
Get-Date -Date $startDate -UFormat "%Y%m%d-%h%M%S"
```

Answer (score 1):

-UFormat switch belongs to the Get-Date commandlet.  So you would use this syntax:

Get-Date ($startDate) -UFormat "%Y%m%d" for example.

And if I am interpreting what you "really" want in your date format string, you have incorrect case on the hour token.

"%Y%m%d-%h%M%S" Should be

Get-Date ($startDate) -UFormat %Y%m%d-%H%M%S

Which will return: 20210102-200000

These tokens - at least where I get them - are from TCL.

Goggle tcl clock manual page for a complete list.

I usually use -UFormat switch - I know TCL tokens and don't have to worry about escaping letters used in Microsoft date string tokens.

Get-Date ($startDate) -Format "Hello-yyyyMMdd-HHmmss-World"

returns: 20ello-20210102-200000-Worl2 because the H and d are tokens - and would need to be escaped \H \d

whereas

Get-Date ($startDate) -UFormat "Hello-%Y%m%d-%H%M%S-World"

returns: Hello-20210102-200000-World